# Why date format is automatically changed on converting JSON to CSV in c#?

Tags: c#, json, csv

I have a large json that contains date values in a string. I am converting my JSON to CSV using below code :

```
StringWriter csvString = new StringWriter();
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(csvString))
{
    csv.Configuration.SkipEmptyRecords = true;
    csv.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = delimiter;

    using (var dt = jsonStringToTable(jsonContent))
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            csv.WriteField(column.ColumnName);
        }
        csv.NextRecord();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                csv.WriteField(row[i]);
            }
            csv.NextRecord();
        }
    }
```

JSON value is :

```
[{
    "Amount": "35.80",
    "Parentid": "abcd",
    "code": "CGL",
    "Effective_Date": "2016-04-25T18:30:00"
}]
```

Once this JSON is converted, above date automatically changes to format 25/4/2016 6:30:00 PM

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "date automatically changes to format"? If you're looking at a `DateTime`, it doesn't *have* a format...

Comment: Posting jsonStringToTable would help

Comment: Have a look at `csv.WriteField`. That may be the one that writes the data in that format

Comment: Either you're doing an (implicit) .ToString on a read DateTime. Or you're reading the resulting CSV using Excel, which automatically formats dates it detects to the current locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jsonStringToTable is what's making your JSON string value a date according to your locale. When it's converted back to string it's converted in that locale's default format.

In order to solve this you need to specify a condition in your loop when you're going through the datatable fields:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{  
   var myVal = i == myDateColumnIndex ? row[i].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"):row[i].ToString();
   csv.WriteField(myVal );
}
```

if your column is your date column (e.g. by index), then do a string ([this might help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)) of your preferred format.

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses the local (the machine from where you ran your code) regional date time format options, when converting date/time to string.